# How to start AVD emulator without device frame

Tags: android-emulator

When starting avd emulator, there is phone device like border around the emulator. How can I start emulator without that frame? It's taking too much screen space.

Answer (score 5):

The following was implemented on a default configuration.

[image: AVD Manager Dialog Box]

Open AndroidStudio (AS) AVD Manager, click the "pencil icon" to edit the virtual device settings, uncheck the box next to "Enable Device Frame". Click "

NOTE: you may have to click the "Show Advanced Settings" button and scroll down to Device Frame.

[image: android virtual device settings image]

Comment: I just updated Android Studio and no longer see that as an option.

Comment: I see it on 3.4.1